# How to run a Python SimpleHTTPServer and have execution continue in a script?

Tags: python, shell

I have a script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill -f SimpleHTTPServer
python -m SimpleHTTPServer & > /dev/null
```

When I run this script I want execution to continue, but it hangs at `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...` and waits for further input. How do I make it continue while still running the SimpleHTTPServer? My build systems all hang when I run this command.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. I suggest you outline what you are trying to do a bit more.  For example does the process need to persist across sessions?

Comment: Did you try pressing enter after it ran? If you get your prompt back, it's not hanging

Comment: Add another the `&` at the end: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer &>/dev/null &`. Depending on where it runs you might also want to make it use `nohup`.

Comment: You can also use the `nohup` command to  release the terminal and redirect the process output to the `nohup.out` file.
Try `nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer &`.

Comment: All of these result in the same thing - it needs me to hit enter before it'll give me the shell prompt back. I'm on a Mac but I need this to work on Linux boxes too. I'm basically trying to start a very simpe HTTP server so I can run some automated tests using it. It needs to persist for a little while and then I'll kill it with a different script.

Comment: @NickLocking Tried `python -m SimpleHTTPServer &>/dev/null &` (note there are no spaces between the first `&` and `>`) on both Mac & Linux and it works (aka it doesn't require pressing enter and so on).